# As a boy kissing a men by loving him but not with the desire of sex is permissible in islam?

Tags: halal-haram

I am a boy.I like a men and he also like me.We usually kiss each other as the sign of love.We hug each other also as the sign of love.We both do not have any sexual desire.We just love each other and as the sign of love we kiss and hug each other.The men is not so much acknowledged about halal haram so I telk him hala haram and i have given him a book to read(name major sins by imama azzahabi).I always tell him to fear Allah and we both sincere about salat.After all is it permissible to kiss that men as tge sign of love?

Comment: How old are you and are your parents aware that this is happening?

Comment: I am 16 and my parents don't know about this at all.

Comment: You should inform them immediately.

Comment: If my parents make a bad idea about me!!

Comment: What's your answer in this regard?

Comment: Its your parents responsibility to investigate what is going on and then to make you understand what is right and wrong. You also need to inform them for your own safety. Being intimate with a stranger like this is not normal.

Comment: Brother I will let my parents know about that.Brother is it permissible to do?

Comment: Is it permissible in islam to kiss any man normally as a man?

Answer (score 1):

It is a door to Zina so no you cannot do it. Even if you say that you have no intention to have sex you never know what could happen you are already at the point of kissing/a relationship and as long as you don’t get out of that it will escalate. Causing problems with your family, ruin your image and ruin your drive for halal relationships.
“And come not near to unlawful sex. Verily, it is a Faahishah (i.e. anything that transgresses its limits: a great sin, and an evil way that leads one to hell unless Allaah Forgives him)”
[al-Isra’ 17:32]
“ Fighting has been enjoined upon you while it is hateful to you. But perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not.”
Surah 2:216
This verse may be very helpful for your case.